# send file to server curl php

Tags: php, curl

I have small php app, that have some files inside. I want to send one of the files from one server to another server with using curl.

**I already have file on server, I just need to send it to another server.**

I execute the following code:

```
$url = "http://localhost:3919/";
$myCurl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($myCurl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt_array($myCurl, array(
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_POST => true,
                CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
                CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD => true,
                // CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                //  "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"),
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
                    "inputFile" => new CurlFile('@' . './Files/example.docx'))
            ));

$response = curl_exec($myCurl);
curl_close($myCurl);
return $response;
```

But it doesn't trigger the server. So what should I do wrong?

For example in other case (other app) I use this:

```
$file = $_FILES["inputFile"];
curl_setopt_array($myCurl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
    CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"),
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        "inputFile" => new CurlFile($file["tmp_name"], $file["type"], $file["name"]))
));
```

And it works perfectly.

Comment: Have you checked [curl_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php)?  Also, you say that you want to send the file to "another" server, but you're using a local url (with an odd port for a web server too).

Comment: It's my another app with localhost, where I get file. Yes, I've checked curl_error(), it's empty.

Comment: Okay, so then what exactly does "it doesn't trigger the server" mean?  Is it supposed to return something?  If so, provide the code that should be generating that response as well as what the current response is.  Right now you're basically just saying "it's not working", which isn't helpful.

Comment: I just want to know why this code doesn't send file to server (server it's c# web api app where I set breakpoint to look at parameters that is sent from php file)

Comment: So far, you haven't provided anything to show that it's _not_ sending the file.  Also, I'm pretty sure that if you're using `CurlFile`, you don't use the `@` prefix.  `CurlFile` is a replacement for that method of sending files.  You should see that in your working code you don't have that.

Comment: So, how can I resolve my issue?

Answer (score 1):

Using the curl_file_create works for me on sending files in curl.

```
$target_url = 'http://localhost:3919/';

$post = array (
    'file' => curl_file_create('Location of the file')
);

$ch = curl_init ($target_url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$msg=curl_exec ($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

if($info['http_code'] === 200){
    $returnMessage = json_decode($msg,1);
} else {
    $returnMessage['file_type'] = 'error';
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: it also didn't help me.I see this in `$info` variable https://www.screencast.com/t/stsvNMVOUaEZ

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need validate if exist files on your post and this a example complete:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" encoding='multipart/form-data' method='post' action="form.php">
  <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" value="choose">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
<?
if ( isset($_FILES['uploadedfile']) ) {
 $filename  = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'];
 $handle    = fopen($filename, "r");
 $data      = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
 $POST_DATA = array(
   'file' => base64_encode($data)
 );
 $curl = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, '<span style="color: red;">http://extserver.com/handle.php</span>');
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $POST_DATA);
 $response = curl_exec($curl);
 curl_close ($curl);
 echo "<h2>File Uploaded</h2>";
}
?>
```

this is a example with encrypt the file with base64.

**your external server**

```
$encoded_file = $_POST['file'];
$decoded_file = base64_decode($encoded_file);
/* Now you can copy the uploaded file to your server. */
file_put_contents('<span style="color: red;">subins</span>', $decoded_file);
```

Comment: No, I already have file on server, I just need to send it to another server.

Comment: on this case you need attachment the file

Comment: When I try your example, I see this https://www.screencast.com/t/WsQkD3BHa
For file path I tried `'D:\\Share\\Programs\\xampp\\htdocs\\Files\\example.docx'` and 
`./Files/example.docx` and 
`http://localhost/Files/example.docx`. But I would like url independent path to file (not hardcoded).